# UIImage overlay with color: bad result

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I need to overlay a small png with a flat color.
The code i use is:

```
- (UIImage *)overlayWithColor:(UIColor *)overlayColor {


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    [overlayColor setFill];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);


    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return coloredImg;

}
```

but the result isn't very smooth...here the original image (the black one) and the image with overlay (the white one)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is as follows (assuming you are iOS7-only):
Invert the original image: Edit it in Photoshop or something similar so that the black lines are transparent (alpha), and the white space is not (it doesn't matter what color it is, as long as it is not transparent).
Then in code:

```
imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[imageView.image setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Where imageView is view that contains your image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a non-retina (with scale factor 1.0) graphics context with this line of code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
```

You can see this in the documentation

> This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of 1.0.

Instead you should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` directly and pass 0.0 for the scale factor (which is documented to be the same as the main screen's scale factor):

> If you specify a value of `0.0`, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

I.e. you should use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size,  
                                       NO,   // opaque or not. NO means transparent
                                       0.0); // scale factor. 0 means same as device
```